# Accessing shared outlook inbox in python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I have a shared inbox in outlook and I want to write some code that would get me the emails from the shared inbox. Right now I can get the emails from my main inbox, but I want to do it for another inbox.

This is the code so far:

```
import os
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('Some Magic Folder')
messages = inbox.Items
```

My guess is that I shouldn't be looking at the GetDefaultFolder method but something else, but I'm not quite sure where to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575.aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
  myRecipient.Resolve 
  If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
  End If 
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Set CalendarFolder = _ 
  myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _ 
  (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
  CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: inbox = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(6)
  File "<COMObject GetNamespace>", line 3, in GetSharedDefaultFolder
TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object

 getting that error

Comment: Did you pass a valid recipient object to the GetSharedDefaultFolder method?

Comment: ah, I think I may know how to approach this. Thanks!